# I am using levels(dataset$variable) and it is still showing a NULL output

Tags: r, dataframe

This is all using R in Rstudio. I am hoping for an quick solution. I am currently running through a Udacity R course, and they are asking me to run the **below code** to show the levels for the variable `age.range` in a dataset called `reddit`:

```
levels(reddit$age.range)
```

However, it keeps returning with the same output.

```
NULL
```

In their video tutorial with the same data set it seems to be working fine, and showing a clear series of levels for this variable, so I really don't understand what the issue is. Please help.

```
> str(reddit)
'data.frame':   32754 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ id               : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ gender           : int  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ age.range        : chr  "25-34" "25-34" "18-24" "25-34" ...
 $ marital.status   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ employment.status: chr  "Employed full time" "Employed full time" "Freelance" "Freelance" ...
 $ military.service : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ children         : chr  "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
 $ education        : chr  "Bachelor's degree" "Bachelor's degree" "Some college" "Bachelor's degree" ...
 $ country          : chr  "United States" "United States" "United States" "United States" ...
 $ state            : chr  "New York" "New York" "Virginia" "New York" ...
 $ income.range     : chr  "$150,000 or more" "$150,000 or more" "Under $20,000" "$150,000 or more" ...
 $ fav.reddit       : chr  "getmotivated" "gaming" "snackexchange" "spacedicks" ...
 $ dog.cat          : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ cheese           : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
```

```
> table(reddit$age.range)

      18-24       25-34       35-44       45-54       55-64 65 or Above    Under 18 
      15802       11575        2257         502         140          60        2330
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without code, and sample data it is not possible to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: how do I add them to the question?

Comment: Click on "Edit"

Comment: the data set is very large and is a csv folder, how can I attach?

Comment: You can get the structure of data using `dput(df)` in RConsole (assuming the name of your data frame is df). Paste the output of `dput` in your question.

Comment: To start with just show us the output of `str(mydata)`

Comment: Thankyou guys, apologies for the delay. This is new to me. I have added str(mydata) and table(mydata$variable) to try and help. I tried dput(mydata) and str(mydata) but the dataset is so large it exceeded my console scroll bar. Hope this helps, let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the variable is of type `character`. For `levels()` to work, it needs to be a factor. So this should work:

```
reddit$age.range <- as.factor(reddit$age.range)
levels(reddit$age.range)
```

The reason for this problem might be that you imported these data using `read.csv` or `read.table`, with the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. The default value for this changed fairly recently. It's a good idea to always specify this option explicitly when loading data.

Comment: Thankyou very much, this solved the issue. I will ensure to keep this in mind going forwards, apologies if this was a simple issue. I am new to not only R but coding itself, but your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I’m guessing the course you’re following was created before R 4.0. In R4 the default value for the “stringsAsFactors” argument to data.frame was changed from true to false.

Comment: Ah, I did have to redownload/update R soon after starting the course, I assume some of the course will therefore have issues and be slightly outdated. Thankyou for elaborating. It is very useful to know and I may be returning with more issues in the future.

Comment: Just for the sake of the course, in places it doesn't specifically says otherwise - I'd suggest to add "stringsAsFactors=true" to every `data.frame` creation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers here from Ofek Shilon and Robert Long, the problem is using levels for non-factor data. The following worked for me on my dataset (Ogle, 2016 - Introductory Fisheries Analyses with R). The levels() code example that I was following in this book wasn't working, probably due to an update at some point. The fix:

```r
str(inchAll) #to see data characterisation
inchAll$species <- as.factor(inchAll$species) #to change to factor data
levels(inchAll$species)
```